# VBA copy the content of a cell minus the content of another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried googling for an answer but unfortunately I was not able to find anything that fulfills my specific needs in this situation.

I have two cells of which the latter one consists of a word which can also be found in the first cell. I want to copy all contents from cell 1 to cell 3 minus the content of cell 2.

For example:

**Cell 1**

> This Is Sample Text

**Cell 2**

> Sample

**Cell 3**

> This Is Text

Is there any way to do this either via a VB macro or even with a simple formula?

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check out the SUBSTITUTE formula.

Comment: @SJR Troll Mode ON : LOL "specific needs"!

Comment: Or `WorksheetFunction.Replace` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194800.aspx

Comment: LOL Answers! Troll Mode OFF *(I'd better log out to keep it that way!)*

Comment: @R3uK - perverse incentives ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub removeYourString()
   Dim withParts As String
   Dim removeParts As String
   Dim withoutParts As String

   withParts = Range("A1").Value
   removeParts = Range("A2").Value & " "
   withoutParts = Replace(withParts, removeParts, "")
   Range("A3").Value = withoutParts
End Sub
```

Remove all in column

```
Sub removeYourString()
   Dim withParts As String
   Dim removeParts As String
   Dim withoutParts As String
   Dim i As Integer

   For i = 1 To 100
        withParts = Range("A" & i).Value
        removeParts = Range("B" & i).Value & " "
        withoutParts = Replace(withParts, removeParts, "")
        Range("C" & i).Value = withoutParts
   Next i
End Sub
```

Or use a formula and put in c1 through c100

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1 & " ","")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, pokemon_Man. This is exactly what I was looking for. How would one go about extending the code so it refers to whole columns rather than cells? For example take the entries of A1 to A100 and remove the coresponding B1 to B100 entry from it and put that into C1 to C100.

Comment: @D.Todor- there really is no need for VBA when there is a perfectly good worksheet formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this formula in cell3:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT([Cell1],FIND([Cell2],[Cell1],FIND([Cell2],[Cell1])+1)-1),RIGHT([Cell1],FIND([Cell2],[Cell1])+LEN([Cell2])+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on SJR's suggestion of `SUBSTITUTE`:

Use the following formula: `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,""))`. Put this in C1 and copy down the column. This will remove the word in column 2 from the string in column 1. The `TRIM` function gets rid of extra spaces where the word is removed. If a word can occur as a subset of another word (e.g. the word is 'test' but your string is 'Test, testing, 1, 2, 3') you can add a space to the end of your filter word so that 'testing' doesn't match.

If the word occurs multiple times, it will remove all matches unless you specify which occurrence you want to remove. changing `(A1,B1,"")` to `(A1,B1,"",1)` will remove only the first occurring match. So 'Test1 test2 test3' would be changed to '1 test2 test3'